# Нужна помощь в выводе List<T>

Tags: c#, list, консоль

Этот метод рисует меню, он выводит сами строки и по средству переключения стрелочками меняет цвет при выборе пункта. Но выводит он не каждый пункт меню (их 3), а все вместе и 3 раза (из-за вложенного `foreach` в `for`) и я не могу понять, как мне оставить эту смену цвета, но выводить каждый пункт меню по 1 разу.

Я переписал элементы меню с массивов на листы и вот возникла такая проблема.

```
public static void DrawMenu(List<MenuItems> items, int index, string text)
{
    ConsoleHelper.ClearScreen();
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == index)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        }
        foreach (MenuItems item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Text);
        }

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

https://gitlab.com/IlyaKvashnin/TimeTrees/-/tree/lab2-add-and-write
Прикрепляю гитлаб, если нужна вся программа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужен здесь никакой `foreach`.

```cs
public static void DrawMenu(List<MenuItems> items, int index, string text)
{
    ConsoleHelper.ClearScreen();
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == index)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(items[i].Text);

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

> Я переписал элементы меню с массивов на листы и вот возникла такая проблема.

Зачем? Я не вижу, что вы где-либо модифицируете списки. А если коллекцию не надо модифицировать, то чем вам массив не угодил? А вообще для данного метода разницы нет, список там или массив.

У вас наверное был `string[]`, но вы создали класс `MenuItems` - это хорошо. Перестало работать, как раз когда вы тип поменяли, а не списки ввели. Можно было использовать `MenuItems[]` вместо списка, и получился бы тот же эффект. Кстати, у вас внутри класса `MenuItems` один айтем, тогда почему он называется не `MenuItem`? Подумайте над названием.

Comment: Про MenuItem верное замечание, исправил, а `foreach` я просто использовал чтобы вывести, не мог придумать как еще выводить, спасибо